Skip arguments in JS
I have a function example(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4) and the function uses arg4 for something. Is there a way for me to skip the other arguments instead of having them as unused variables.
I tried example(,,,arg4) but it does not work

You can't skip them, but you can provide default values (empty strings, null, etc.) depending on how you have implemented the function. That being said, a better approach would be to change the function to accept an object whose properties you can include/omit as desired.

There is no support in JavaScript for what you want to do. Therefore, the best approach is to design your API so that your more optional arguments are at the end of the list, and your more commonly passed arguments are at the beginning.

You’re asking about defining a function with unused parameters, right? Not calling one?

If arguments 1 through to 3 are unused and only argument 4 is needed/used inside the function's body - why do you define the function that way?

You could create a wrapper function that takes an object instead of four arguments, and translates that to a call of the original function. Then you can target the arguments you wish to provide by name:


function example(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4) {
    console.log(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4); // Mock implementation: just prints the four arguments
}

// Wrapper that takes object instead of separate arguments
function example2({arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4}={}) {
    return example(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
}

// Example use: only providing arg4:
example2({arg4: 1});




If you're looking for a compact way to insert a bunch of null values into your function arguments, maybe this would work for you.
Create a helper function which generates an array of null values.
const no = howMany => Array(howMany).fill(null);

Then when you call your function, just spread the result of this helper into your arguments.
i.e.
//instead of 
example(null, null, null, someVar4);
//do
example(...no(3), someVar4);

If you have control over the construction of this function you're using, there are better ways to accomplish a task like this, but as a direct answer to the question you asked, hopefully this helps :) If you'd like any explanation / clarification, please ask.

You can do this if you change your params and the way they are passed. Look at this example:


function test({ a = null, b = null, c = null } = {}) {
  a ? console.log({ 'a': a }): ''
  b ? console.log({ 'b': b }): ''
  c ? console.log({ 'c': c }): ''
}

// Calling the function with all parameters
test({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 });

// Calling the function with only one parameter
test({ b: 'Only pass b' });

// Calling the function with no parameters
test();



